# how to get rid of addin security of winform

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

[Security addin window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jqiD.gif)

Hi,
i have multiple external command created and dock it into it's own Revit tab. however, when i add a winform to one of the commands it is now asking me for another security addin pop-up window when Revit launch. as you can see in GiF. Is there a way to get it rid of this?

here is my code for external command interface:

` [Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
    public class DeleteUnusedFilter : IExternalCommand
    {

```
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        UIDocument uidoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
        Document doc = uidoc.Document;

             var Form = new DeleteFilter(commandData);
            try
            {
                var fltr = new FilterData(doc).GetUnusedFilter();
                if (fltr.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageInfo.Display("No unused View Filters in Document");
                    Form.Close();
                return Result.Cancelled;
                }

                Form.ShowDialog();
                return Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result.Succeeded;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                message = ex.Message;
                return Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result.Failed;
            }

    }
}`
```

and here is for winform code:

```
 public partial class DeleteFilter : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    Document doc;
    List<Element> FiltersToDelete;
    public DeleteFilter(ExternalCommandData commandData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        doc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
    }



    private void DeleteFilter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        callonload();

    }
}
```

here is for UiApplication that register the plugin:

```
 //ribbon for delete unused filter
        string path3 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var button3 = new PushButtonData("Button2", "Delete\n Unused Filter", path2, "RevitCode.DeleteUnusedFilter");
        var panel3 = application.CreateRibbonPanel("Angelo Tools", "Delete");

        Uri imagePath3 = new Uri(@"C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2019\icon\DeleteFtr.png");
        BitmapImage image3 = new BitmapImage(imagePath3);
        button3.ToolTip = "Delete Unused View Filters";
        PushButton Push_button3 = panel3.AddItem(button3) as PushButton;
        Push_button3.LargeImage = image3;

        return Result.Succeeded;
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As we already discussed in the [Revit API forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160) thread on [Another Security Addin windows pop-up after adding winform](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/another-security-addin-windows-pop-up-after-adding-winform/td-p/9096129/jump-to/first-unread-message):

This is normal and expected.

Each individual external command and external application is individually checked.

Therefore, adding a new external command with its new Windows form will produce a new security check.

You can get rid of them either by clicking 'load always' or by signing your add-in.

For more details, please refer to the Revit API online help documentation on [Digitally Signing Your App](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2020/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Add_In_Integration_Digitally_Signing_Your_Revit_Add_in_Digitally_Signing_Your_App_html).

You can also take a look at previous discussions of this topic in the threads on:

- [Code signing of Revit Addins](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/code-signing-of-revit-addins/td-p/5981560)
- [Security prompt for unsigned add-ins](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/security-prompt-for-unsigned-add-ins/td-p/7299954)